# Image classification - Car or Not

Tags: image-processing

I am building a system that can classify cars based on damage severity. In this system I needed to insert a module that can tell me if an uploaded image is car or not. I am using tensorflow for this purpose. I only have one idea that I can have images of car in one folder and some random images of other things in other folder. But this is not feasible at all as I cannot add images of every possible thing.

Is there any other solution for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**First solution**

You can find images of "every possible thing" in some **dataset as CIFAR100**, (you can specify than you don't want car images before the downloading) then you can train your network to identify car images from other ones.

**Second solution**

Use a **pretrained model**, many models have been already trained to recognize cars in Tensorflow, you just have to pick one.

**Third solution**

If you have a folder with car images, you can train a **Generative Adversial Network** to generate some pictures of cars from a random vector, after training the discriminator should be able to recognise cars !

Comment: but the system is predicting damage, so if the car is highly damaged the system must recognize its a car and also highly damaged right ? If I train the model with car images will be efficient ?

Comment: if you add some noise to the input and put some dropout in the layers, you need more training data but at the end the network should be very good at recognise cars, even if they are damaged...

Comment: so any model I choose I should have cars along with damaged cars in one class of images and images of "every possible thing" in the other class?

Comment: Is this process possible with just training the model with car images and making it predict whether it is car or not looking at the training set  ? Like, If the image given matches somewhat with the images in trainset it is a car and if not it is not a car .